# Recursion without recursive call?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, recursion

Found this on /prog/. I actually GDB'd it, and yes, it was truly a recursion. But how did it happen?

```
// This works on 32-bit x86 Linux with gcc as long as you don't enable optimization.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void factorial(int in, int *out)
{
  *(&in-1)-=5-5*(1/in);
  *out*=in--;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
  int result=1;
  int number=0;

  if (argc!=2) 
    exit(1);

  number=atoi(argv[1]);
  if (number<1)
    exit(2);

  factorial(number, &result);
  printf("%d! = %d\n", number, result);
  return 0;
}


$ ./factorial 3
3! = 6

$ ./factorial 5
5! = 120
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sweet. ;)

This is extremely non-portable code that works only on x86. What it's doing is changing the return address on the stack so that if `in>1`, the function returns not to the instruction *following* the `call` instruction, but to the call instruction itself. A call instruction on x86 is five bytes (one opcode plus the 4-byte address of the call destination), so five needs to be subtracted from the return address.

This

```
*(&in-1)-=5-5*(1/in);
```

is just an obfuscated way of saying

```
if(in>1)
    *(&in-1)-=5;
```

And `&in-1` is where the return address lives on the stack.

Comment: @Martin B why it is only available on x86?

Comment: @Bakudan: You could probably do similar things on other architectures, but this particular "party trick" is specific to a) the x86 calling convention (i.e. where does the return address live) and b) the fact that an x86 call instruction is 5 bytes.

Comment: @Martin,...ca u please give me an explaination.i m not able to get the clear scenario...

Comment: i mean the return address of the stack is changed but what happens den...?

Comment: @Abhimanyu: To understand this, you really need to be familiar with x86 assembly and calling conventions -- see for example the explananation of the cdecl calling convention on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl

Comment: This code does not even work reliably on x86. A good optimizing compiler will choose its own calling convention for `static` functions which are never called through function pointers.

Comment: Also `in--` should be optimized just to `in` because the value of `in` is never used after that.

Comment: R..: Good points -- it certainly is worth pointing out that this hack is very "brittle" in the sense that it relies not only on properties of the x86 architecture but also on knowledge of the specific code that a particular version of gcc will create with particular compiler settings... Still a nice brain teaser though! ;)

Answer (score 8):

It's corrupting return addresses on the stack to cause the recursion to happen.

```
*(&in-1)-=5-5*(1/in);
```

`&in-1` is probably the pushed return address. the rest is just unpleasant magic.

Answer (score 0):

As said before *(&in-1) is the return address<strike>, 5 (I guess) is the size of the function (in words?) and it substract both to get the address where the function begins.</strike>

<strike>EDIT: Since I think the change to the return address is permanent I don't understand why 5 is subtracted while in > 1;</strike>

EDIT2: See the comments

The assembler return instruction only jumps to the address that is on the top of the stack.

Due to the calling convention the parameters are pushed to the stack and removed from it by the caller. Since there is only one real call there is no recursion, the parameters and the return address (pointer) are shared among the iterations.

It is more like a loop than a recursive function.

Comment: True, this is more like a loop than a real recursion, because no nested stack frames ever get built.

Comment: To answer your question about whether the change to the return address is permament... no, it's not, since the return address gets popped back off the stack when `factorial` returns. The next `call` instruction from `main()` then pushes a new, pristine return address onto the stack... so the return address needs to be modified again. All of this goes on until `in==1`, at which point we actually want to return from `factorial()` the normal way -- so we don't modify the return address.

Comment: So the call is executed again. I did't think that. That explains why 5, it just changes the return point one instruction back. Thank you.